# How to convert a single row into one column?

Tags: valueconverter, row-value-expression

How to convert columns of one row into one row each?

Having data in table as below:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
+------+------+------+------+
|  a1  |  a2  |  a3  |  a4  |
+------+------+------+------+
```

required output: all values in the row should go in single column as below.

```
+---------------+
|   All_cols    |
+---------------+
|  a1,a2,a3,a4  |
+---------------+
```

Like in image: Here `mytable` always have one record, so I need the output as below.

[image]

want to avoid below sql as it requires multiple joins:

```
select a1.name from  accounts a1 where a1.id='658f3b73-8260-5a7a-ae7e-54c25deded36'

union

Select a2.name from accounts a1
left join accounts a2 on a1.id=a2.parent_id where a1.id='658f3b73-8260-5a7a-ae7e-54c25deded36'

union

Select a3.name from accounts a1
left join accounts a2 on a1.id=a2.parent_id
left join accounts a3 on a2.id=a3.parent_id where a1.id='658f3b73-8260-5a7a-ae7e-54c25deded36'

union

Select a4.name from accounts a1
left join accounts a2 on a1.id=a2.parent_id
left join accounts a3 on a2.id=a3.parent_id
left join accounts a4 on a3.id=a4.parent_id where a1.id='658f3b73-8260-5a7a-ae7e-54c25deded36'

union

Select a5.name from accounts a1
left join accounts a2 on a1.id=a2.parent_id
left join accounts a3 on a2.id=a3.parent_id
left join accounts a4 on a3.id=a4.parent_id
left join accounts a5 on a4.id=a5.parent_id where a1.id='658f3b73-8260-5a7a-ae7e-54c25deded36'
```

Comment: Dear, It is converting row data into single column value as in image, thank you for your response.

Comment: dear I just corrected the image as my table always have one record.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a `UNION` on four single calls

```
SELECT col1 FROM mytable
UNION
SELECT col2 FROM mytable
UNION
SELECT col3 FROM mytable
UNION
SELECT col4 FROM mytable
```

will output

[image]

You say that

> mytable always have one record.

Be aware that if you have more than one record, it's wise to use the same `WHERE` condition on each `SELECT` statement above.

Comment: it works, is there any simple way, because the values are not coming from one table it requires multiple joins, adding my exact sql.